# Image only paints within original bounds

Tags: java, swing

I want to animate several jpgs in a JFrame, I'll show you some extracts:

My class constructor that extends JFrame

```
super(title);
setLayout(null);
setResizable(false);
setSize(Settings.windowWidth, Settings.windowHeight);
setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
setLocationRelativeTo(null);
setVisible(true);
```

My class constructor that extends JPanel

```
i = new ImageIcon(image).getImage();
setSize(i.getWidth(this),i.getHeight(this));
setBounds(x, y, i.getWidth(this), i.getHeight(this));
```

The overwritten method

```
@Override
public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
    super.paintComponent(g);
    g.drawImage(i, getX(), getY(), null);
}
```

Yes, I know null layout isn't preferrable, but unless you have a better idea for absolute positioning I'll stick with it for now.

Above code does paint the image, starting at (x,y), but not completely.
For 50 and 100 it shows this:

[image]

Which is pretty much: It only paints the image within a 256x256 box (image dimensions) from 0,0, no matter where it has been relocated to.

Any advice, help, solutions, suggestions?
If you need more code, ask me, just don't feel like putting everything around it in here, too ;)

Comment: *"If you need more code, ask me, just don't feel like putting everything around it in here, too"* - Generally you should post a [mcve] that is runnable for us.

Comment: *"Yes, I know null layout isn't preferrable, but unless you have a better idea for absolute positioning I'll stick with it for now."* - I have plenty of suggestions, but without further context to what you are trying to achieve it's impossible to make suggestions

Comment: Alright, thanks for this, I'll take that into account next time!

Comment: I stated I wanted to create some animations based on moving images, there is not much more behind it so far.

Comment: @AlgorithmicStructure You've provided a bunch of out-of-context code snippets which mean nothing to use at all.  You should consider providing an example, which is both compilable and runnable which demonstrates your problem, read the link LuxxMiner provided

Comment: Yeah, I read that :p I expected it to be a simple config missed on my part.

Comment: *Alright, thanks for this, I'll take that into account next time!*, Don't leave it until next time, better edit your post with an example we can copy-paste to see your app running and give your a better approach

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My gut feeling is you don't understand how component painting actually works...

First, you do this...

```
i = new ImageIcon(image).getImage();
setSize(i.getWidth(this),i.getHeight(this));
setBounds(x, y, i.getWidth(this), i.getHeight(this));
```

Then you do this...

```
g.drawImage(i, getX(), getY(), null);
```

which seems to be painting the image at a offset position from the components origin, but since the component is sized to match the size of the image, the image is cropped at the component boundaries.

When a component is painted, the `Graphics` context's origin is set to the components location, meaning that `0x0` is now the components top/left corner.

You can test this by using `setBorder(new LineBorder(Color.RED))`, which will show you the physical bounds of the component

In your case, something like

```
    g.drawImage(i, 0, 0, this);
```

In your case, you should be moving the component not the image.

Personally, I'd add the `JPanel` to the `JFrame` using a `BorderLayout`, then you can simply move the image anywhere within the context of the component itself.  Remember to override `getPreferredSize` to return an appropriate size for your purposes so the frame can be packed around it more effectively.

It's tricky to do animation with components (not impossible, there's just a lot to take into account), generally it's just easier to paint directly to a canvas like a `JPanel`, but that's me

See [Painting in AWT and Swing](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/painting-140037.html) and [Performing Custom Painting](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/) for more details about how painting works

Comment: Yep, I'm still not 100% into Swing, that was the problem, thanks dude! :D

Answer (score 4):

There is no need for custom painting:

1. Add the ImageIcon to a JLabel and add the JLabel to a JPanel
2. Change the location of the label on the panel when you want to animate it.

Or, if you do custom painting then there is no need for a null layout.

1. You override the `getPreferredSize()` method of the JPanel and add your panel to the frame.
2. Then in the `paintComponent()` method you can paint the image where every you want withing the bounds of the preferred size that you set.